# how to open the last created text file?

Tags: command-line

I know how to use `cat` to quickly open a file, but one of my programs generates some log files with super long/weird names, and typing `-ls` to find the name is really not efficient.

How can I open the last text file just created into a folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The simple case. If you know your file names are sane (no spaces, globbing characters, newlines etc), you can just do:

   ```
   cat $(ls -t | head -n1)
   ```
2. To deal with spaces and globbing characters, just quote:

   ```
   cat "$(ls -t | head -n1)"
   ```
3. If your file names are arbitrary and you need to make this work for *any* file name, including those with newlines in their name, use:

   ```
   cat "$(stat --printf '%n/%Y\0' * | sort -rz -t'/' -k 2 | head -z -n 1 | cut -d'/' -z -f 1 )"
   ```

   #### Explanation

   - `stat --printf '%n/%Y\0'` : print the file name and its modification date ([in seconds since the epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)), separated by a `/` and then a NUL (`\0`). I am using `/` and `\0` because they are the *only* two characters not allowed in a file/directory name.
   - `sort -rz -t'/' -k 2` : sort on the second `/`-separated field. The `-z` makes `sort` read NUL-delimited data.
   - `head -z -n 1` : keep only the fist NUL-delimited (`-z`) line.
   - `cut -d'/' -z -f 1` : print only the first `/`-delimited field, the file name. Again, the `-z` makes `cut` deal with NUL-delimited data.
4. Use `zsh` instead of `bash` as your shell, and just run:

   ```
   cat *(om[1])
   ```

You could set any of these (preferably 3 since it is the most robust) as an alias by adding this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias cat_last='cat "$(stat --printf "%n/%Y\0" * | sort -rz -t"/" -k 2 | head -z -n 1 | cut -d"/" -z -f 1 )" 2>/dev/null'
```

I added the `/dev/null` because on my system the shell complains about a NUL byte being in the input. That doesn't block the command though and there's no reason to keep seeing the error.

Comment: `ls -tr` will show multiple filenames on one line. Better use `ls -tr1`. Or use `ls -t1 | head -1` and save a few keystrokes.

Comment: @Jos no, there's no reason to use `-1` when passing the output of `ls` to a pipe. It does it automatically. Good point about not using `-r` though, I'm used to that and I added it automatically without thinking. Aliases also mentioned.

Comment: thanks! can you please explain what `$(ls -t | head -n1)` does as well?

Comment: @Noobie this is all explained in `man ls` and `man head`. The `-t` just makes `ls` sort files by date and the `head -n1` will print the first line of its input.

Comment: @terdon Thanks, didn't know that the multiple-file layout goes away when using a pipe.